# Use eval with dictionary without losing imported modules in Python2

Tags: python, eval, python-2.x

I have a string to be executed inside my python program and I want to change some variables in the string like x[1], x[2] to something else.
I had previously used eval with 2 arguments (the second being a dict with replaced_word: new_word) but now I noticed I can't use previously imported modules like this. So if I do this

```
from math import log
eval(log(x[1], {x[1]: 1})
```

it will say it doesn't recognize the name log.
How can I use eval like this without losing the global variables?
I can't really make sense of the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval
so an explanation would be useful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build your globals `dict` with [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) as a base:

```
from math import log

# Copy the globals() dict so changes don't affect real globals
eval_globals = globals().copy()
# Tweak the copy to add desired new global
eval_globals[x[1]] = 1

# eval using the updated copy
eval('log(x[1])', eval_globals)
```

Alternatively, you can use [three-arg `eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) to use `globals()` unmodified, but also supply a `local`s `dict` that will be checked (and modified) first, in preference to global values:

```
eval('log(x[1])', globals(), {x[1]: 1})
```

In theory, the latter approach could allow the expression to mutate the original globals, so adding `.copy()` to make it `eval('log(x[1])', globals().copy(), {x[1]: 1})` minimizes the risk of that happening accidentally. But pathological/malicious code could work around that; `eval` is dangerous after all, don't trust it for arbitrary inputs no matter how sandboxed you make it.

Comment: Copying the globals does't seem like a very efficient thing to do. Besides I need to run this eval thousands of times so copying it each time would probably cause too much overhead no?

Comment: @JoaquimFerrer: Heh, I was just updating the answer to add alternate approaches, one of which bypasses the need to copy the `globals()` `dict` at the expense of reducing the sandboxing a bit.

Comment: the input is created by me always so no worries. It works perfectly thanks!

Comment: @JoaquimFerrer: You're welcome. On performance, yes, copying `globals()` could cost a lot. On my system, `globals()` takes ~40 nanoseconds, while `globals().copy()` takes between 500 nanoseconds and 15 usecs, depending on how bloated the global namespace is. That said, even at 15 usecs, you could do this 66K times/second, so if you're doing this single-digit thousands times, it's still going to be faster than a human will notice.